Buck-Boost fault mode on startup and gradual current decrease
I am using the TPS92692 in buck-boost mode with an analog signal to set Iadj and PWM. When I start the circuit, it consistently goes into fault mode and the fault pin is periodically set low. However, after about 5 seconds, everything works fine and the fault pin is no longer set low but after some time, the current also gradually decreases.
The input voltage is 24 V and the circuit powers 7 LEDs (with a forward voltage range of 2.8-3.4 V for each LED). In this case, Iadj is set to 1.46 V and the PWM is 2.44 V
Here is the circuit:

F.Cu :

Inner1.Cu :

Inner2.Cu :

B.Cu :

Current start-up signal (yellow) and fault pin signal (purple) :


Current after about 5 s:

The datasheet of the IC indicated that there is 4 fault conditions :
• Overvoltage across the LED string (VOV> 1.24 V)
• Under voltage across the LED string (VOV< 100 mV)
• Overcurrent across the LED string (14 × V(CSP-CSN) > 1.5 × VIADJ)
• Cycle-by-cycle switch current limit condition (VIS > 250 mV)
As far as overvoltage and undervoltage are concerned, everything seems to be fine, the voltage is below and above the condition when the pin is on fault:

It is more difficult to say about the cycle-by-cycle switching current limitation condition, because the signal is really noisy:

I also noticed that the RSlope should be 180 kohm instead of 150 kohm. I'll try changing the resistor to see if there's any impact.
Update :
I also measured the output of the comp pin (purple) and noticed that the voltage drop below 1.6 V, which also triggers the fault pin (yellow).

By simply bypassing R44 with a 0.1 uF capacitor, here's what we get (purple is the comp pin and yellow is the voltage on led+):

Here's the calculations I made to compensate for the loop:
\begin{align*}
D_{\text{(typ)}} &= 0.475 \\
V_{O(\text{typ\_max})} &= 23.8 \, \text{V} \\
r_{D(\text{typ})} &= 2.31 \, \Omega \\
I_{\text{LED(MIN)}} &= 0.1 \, \text{A} \\
C_{\text{out}} &= 34.7 \times 10^{-6} \, \text{F} \\
L &= 33 \times 10^{-6} \, \text{H} \\
R_{\text{IS}} &= 0.05 \, \Omega
\end{align*}
Open Loop Response of Modulator
\begin{equation*}
\frac{I_{\text{led}}}{V_{\text{comp}}} = G_0 \frac{1 - \frac{s}{\omega_Z}}{1 - \frac{s}{\omega_p}}
\end{equation*}
Small Signal Model Parameter
DC Gain
\begin{align*}
G_0 &= \frac{(1-D) V_O}{R_{\text{is}} \left( V_O + D r_D I_{\text{Led}} \right)} \\
G_0 &= \frac{(1-0.475) \times 23.8}{0.05 \left( 34 + (0.475 \times 2.31 \times 0.1) \right)} = 7.3
\end{align*}
Pole Frequency
\begin{align*}
\omega_p &= \frac{V_O + D r_D I_{\text{Led}}}{V_O r_D C_{\text{out}}} \\
\omega_p &= \frac{23.8 + (0.475 \times 2.31 \times 0.1)}{23.8 \times 2.31 \times 34.7 \times 10^{-6}} = 12.5 \times 10^3
\end{align*}
Zero Frequency
\begin{align*}
\omega_z &= \frac{V_O (1-D)^2}{D L I_{\text{Led}}} \\
\omega_z &= \frac{23.8 (1-0.475)^2}{0.475 \times 33 \times 10^{-6} \times 0.1} = 4.2 \times 10^6
\end{align*}
proportional and integral compensation
\begin{align*}
C_{\text{comp}} &= 8.75 \times 10^{-3} \left( \frac{R_{\text{cs}} G_0}{\omega_z} \right) \\
C_{\text{comp}} &= 8.75 \times 10^{-3} \left( \frac{0.16 \times 7.3}{4.2 \times 10^6} \right) = 2.2 \, \text{nF}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
C_{\text{HF}} &= \frac{C_{\text{comp}}}{100} \\
C_{\text{HF}} &= \frac{2.2 \, \text{nF}}{100} = 22 \, \text{pF}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
R_{\text{comp}} &= \frac{1}{\omega_p C_{\text{comp}}} \\
R_{\text{comp}} &= \frac{1}{12.5 \times 10^3 \times 2.2 \times 10^{-9}} = 39 \, \text{k}\Omega
\end{align*}
Is the error on Rslope involved? Or an integral compensation is more appropiate?

Link to IC? What conditions makes it assert fault according to the datasheet? Which ones have you checked?

Thank you for your reply. I have edited the question.

Do you have persistence/averaging set up on your scope or is it really oscillating that fast? Can you do a single shot? Please measure all the channels you can in one capture to have the same timing.

I imagine that the layout is bad, in addition to other problems. Please edit the question to add the PCB layout - all layers separately so that we can see what's going on.

Thanks to all. The switching frequency is 390 kHz with spread spectrum modulation. I've edited the question to change the plot with the same timing. I've also added the converter layout.

Still persistence issue on your scope capture. Also, 1X probe comes with many drawbacks. Use 10X whenever possible.

Is that ground pour on all four layers?

Yes, sorry for that, but I can't get a better signal for cycle-by-cycle switching current limiting. I guess the inductance propagates the noise even in x10.

Yes the ground is on each layout

Figure 43 of the datasheet uses a much higher damping on the two high side current sense inputs. The differential capacitor is 100 nF and there are two additional capacitors of 10 nF to GND. I had a similar issue without the two GND capacitors, because the switching noise saturated the input stage of the diff amplifier. In my circuit (other IC) best solution was using 2 x 33 nF to GND and no diff cap.

Finally, the problem was with the compensation loop. I have adjusted the values in the compensation loop and everything is working. Thank you for your help !
